# I don't want to obfuscate my files from asset directory, what can be done for this?

Tags: android, crash, apk, proguard, release

App is getting crashed in release mode while reading files from asset directory. In debug mode its working fine. proguard is creating problem. How can I protect those files from obfuscation?

I tried to avoid obfuscating those files from asset dir, but did't get proper solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new folder within your project's directory (e.g., `keep` or `do_not_obfuscate`).

Move the files that you want to protect from obfuscation to this new folder. For example, if you have a file named `myfile.txt` in the asset directory, move it to the new folder.

Open your ProGuard configuration file (usually `proguard-rules.pro`) and add a rule to exclude the files in the keep or do_not_obfuscate folder from obfuscation. Add the following line to the configuration file:

```
-keep class com.yourpackage.keep.** { *; }
```

Replace `com.yourpackage.keep` with the appropriate package name for the folder where you moved the files.